# how to stay connected to my wamp server outside of my home network even when my external IP address changes

Tags: java, php, sql

So I have a wamp server that is up online outside of my network and I am accessing it through Java. my question is.... I have an IP address set in java for my database but when my external IP changes i will have to change the old one in my java code right? or am I wrong? I have the ports forwarded for it.

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for a dynamic dns service.  Take a look at [No IP](https://www.noip.com/free).

Answer (score 0):

As @[Derek Brown](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6395388/derek-brown) says,

but there is will be a lot of problems, 
When i'm saying problems, i talk about security bugs,

First if you connect your WAMP server to public, Hacker will try to get you because you will be easy victim if you dont secure your all files, 
If one of them get a Backdoor tool in your pc via WAMP and have a way to change some .exe files in your PC, he will put a malicious software on your PC,

and we all know if we are in programming mode we use some of default passwords like 'admin' or 'password', or we dont secure our files for SQL and executing vulnerabilities,

I just give you one advice if you want to connect your WAMP server for public, 
you must study how to secure your server and files from all bugs you can found.

Or you can put some firewalls to get into your IP from public.

I hope my advice helps you :)

Answer (score 0):

Setup virtual server or VPN connection on your router and get a dynamic DNS service.

Use your router manufacturer's dynamic DNS if they offer one, or subscribe to a free/cheap service, such as DynDNS, No-IP, etc...

Answer (score 0):

The thing you are trying to achieve can be solved in two ways.

1) use VPN or proxy server to connect your device to wamp server.
(your external IP will appear to be same to server).

2) don't use it at all, that means let the server connect with all IP address and use a specific authentication token for a connection to be established.